# Let $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Fibonacci sequence , then $(4 \mid n \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid F_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I would like to ask if my below proof is fine or if it has any error! Furthermore, I feel that my approach is a bit long, so please suggest any faster or nice approach. Thank you for your help!

**Theorem:**

> Let $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Fibonacci sequence such that $F_0=0,F_1=1$ and $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(4 \mid n \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid F_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Proof:

> Let $P(n)$ is the statement $(4 \mid n \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid F_n)$.
>
> $F_0=0 \implies (4 \mid 0 \wedge 3 \mid F_0) \implies P(0)$ is true.
>
> Assuming $P(k)$ is true for $k \leq n$. There are 4 possible cases in total.
>
> 1. $n+1 = 4x+4$
>
> $4 \mid 4x \implies 3 \mid F_{4x} \implies F_{4x}=3r$.
>
> $4 \not \mid 4x+1 \implies 3 \not \mid F_{4x+1} \implies F_{4x+1}=3s+p$ where $p \in \{1,2\}$.
>
> We have:
>
> $F_{4x+2}=F_{4x+1}+F_{4x}=3r+3s+p$
>
> $F_{4x+3}=F_{4x+2}+F_{4x+1}=3r+6s+2p$
>
> $F_{4x+4}=F_{4x+3}+F_{4x+2}=6r+9s+3p$
>
> $\implies F_{n+1}=F_{4x+4}=6r+9s+3p \implies 3 \mid F_{n+1}$
>
> As a result, $(4 \mid n+1 \wedge 3 \mid F_{n+1})$. This implies $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> 2. $n+1 = 4x+3$
>
> $4 \mid 4x \implies 3 \mid F_{4x} \implies F_{4x}=3r$.
>
> $4 \not \mid 4x+1 \implies 3 \not \mid F_{4x+1} \implies F_{4x+1}=3s+p$ where $p \in \{1,2\}$.
>
> We have:
>
> $F_{4x+2}=F_{4x+1}+F_{4x}=3r+3s+p$
>
> $F_{4x+3}=F_{4x+2}+F_{4x+1}=3r+6s+2p$
>
> $\implies F_{n+1}=F_{4x+3}=3r+6s+2p \implies 3 \not \mid F_{n+1}$
>
> As a result, $(4 \not \mid n+1 \wedge 3 \not \mid F_{n+1})$. This implies $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> 3. $n+1 = 4x+2$
>
> $4 \mid 4x \implies 3 \mid F_{4x} \implies F_{4x}=3r$.
>
> $4 \not \mid 4x+1 \implies 3 \not \mid F_{4x+1} \implies F_{4x+1}=3s+p$ where $p \in \{1,2\}$.
>
> We have:
>
> $F_{4x+2}=F_{4x+1}+F_{4x}=3r+3s+p$
>
> $\implies F_{n+1}=F_{4x+2}=3r+3s+p \implies 3 \not \mid F_{n+1}$
>
> As a result, $(4 \not \mid n+1 \wedge 3 \not \mid F_{n+1})$. This implies $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> 4. $n+1 = 4x+1$
>
> $4 \not \mid 4x-1 \implies 3 \not \mid F_{4x-1} \implies F_{4x-1}=3s+p$ where $p \in \{1,2\}$.
>
> $4 \mid 4x \implies 3 \mid F_{4x} \implies F_{4x}=3r$.
>
> We have:
>
> $F_{4x+1}=F_{4x}+F_{4x-1}=3r+3s+p$
>
> $\implies F_{n+1}=F_{4x+1}=3r+3s+p \implies 3 \not \mid F_{n+1}$
>
> As a result, $(4 \not \mid n+1 \wedge 3 \not \mid F_{n+1})$. This implies $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> To sum up 1, 2, and 3: $P(n+1)$ is true.
>
> By principle of strong induction, $P(n+1)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Simpler proof: take everything mod $3$.  Then sequence is $1,1,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,\ldots$.

Comment: Hi @vadim123, I just learn Peano's axioms and basic properties of addition and multiplication. I have not learned modulo :)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence mod (3) is

$$\{0,1,1,2,0,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,1.....\}$$ Which is periodic and $ a_n=0$ iff $n=4k.$

Similarly you can prove other relations such as $$ m|n \iff F_m|F_n$$

Comment: I just learned Peano's axioms and basic properties of addition and multiplication. I have not learned modulo yet :)

Comment: mod (3) means remainder when divided by 3.  For example 25 mod(3)=1 because when you divide 25 by 3 your get remainder of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Base case

$F_1=1,F_2 = 1, F_3=2, F_4 = 3$

Our position is true for all $n\le 4$

Suppose our proposition is true for all all $n\le 4k$

3 does not divide $F_{4k-1}$

$3|F_{4k}$

3 does not divide $F_{4k-1}$

3 does not divide $F_{4k+1} = F_{4k} + F_{4_k-1}$

3 does not divide $F_{4k+2} = F_{4k+1} + F_{4_k}$

3 does not divide $F_{4k+3} = F_{4k+2}+ f_{4k+1}  = 2F_{4k+1} + F_{4k}$

$3|F_{4k+4} = 3F_{4k+1}+2f_{4k}$

More generally $n|m \iff F_n|F_m$ but that will take a little bit more work.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong about understanding your approach! You meant that we prove $\{n \in N \setminus \{0\} \mid \forall k \leq 4n(4 \mid k \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid F_k)\}=\mathbb{N}$ by induction on $n$.

Comment: And you start from $k=1$ because $(k=0 \implies 4k-1<0)$

Comment: Hi @Dough M, is it possible to prove $(n|m \iff F_n|F_m)$ by principle of strong induction?